# foverlaps data.table || error y's key must be identical to the columns specified in by.y

Tags: r, data.table, devtools

I've two data frames. One with two columns and other with three columns. First data frame has SNP names and its position. The second data frame with three columns has columns with gene name and start and end coordinates of the genes.
I'm interested to perform a join based on the boundaries. If a SNP falls within gene boundaries return it

```
dt_snp<-data.table("SNP"=c(paste("SNP",seq(1:10),sep="")), 
"BP"=c(1100, 89200, 2500, 33000, 5500, 69500, 12000,8800, 23200, 27000  )) ## SNP data

dt_gene<-data.table("GENE"=c("GENE1","GENE2","GENE3","GENE4","GENE5"), 
"START"=c(1000,2100,5000,40000,23000), "END"=c(2000,3000,9000,45000,30000)) ## Gene data

## do a join using data.table
snp_withingenes<-dt_snp[dt_gene, c("SNP","BP","GENE","START","END"), on=.(BP>=START, BP<=END), nomatch=0] # inner join
```

I get desired results with it, however when I perform this task in a R script that is stored in an R package I get a warning for `.` operator. The warning is as:

```
 function_small: no visible global function definition for ‘.’
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    .
```

Thus I'd like to use `foverlaps` but I'm having a hard time understanding and achieve desired results with it. It is counter-intuitive for me

```
foverlaps(dt_snp,dt_gene, by.x=c("SNP","BP"), by.y=c("GENE","START","END"), nomatch=NA, type="any")

Error in foverlaps(dt_snp, dt_gene, by.x = c("SNP", "BP"), by.y = c("GENE",  : 
  The first 3 columns of y's key must be identical to the columns specified in by.y.
```

How should I be able to obtain output as desired?

`data.table_1.13.0` `R v4.0`  windows platform

The `check`from devtools annoys for `.` operator on `R v4.0` `rmarkdown_2.3` `devtools_2.3.1`  UNIX platform

Comment: Couldn't you just replace the `on=.(BP>=START, BP<=END)` by `on=list(BP>=START, BP<=END)` and be done with it?

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, `list` does the job. Been going crazy for 4+ hours with `.` warning from `check` really appreciate your reply and example for `foverlaps`

Comment: Seems like your inner join does not give the correct BP value, though, but rather the START coordinates of the dt_gene...

Comment: ... fixed that in edit

Comment: oh, wow, just noticed it. Thank you~~!!  Why is that? Thank you for catching that. How can I fix it without using `BP2` column as you provided in your solution?

Comment: I think you cannot currently avoid that, unless you want to do a second join to match up the `dt_snp` BP by SNP in `dt_gene`, which probably will be even less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment, here is the foverlaps option, which requires two columns in both `data.tables`, thus seems suboptimal here:

```r
library(data.table)
dt_snp <- data.table("SNP"=c(paste("SNP",seq(1:10),sep="")), 
                   "BP"=c(1100, 89200, 2500, 33000, 5500, 69500, 12000,8800, 23200, 27000  )) ## SNP data

dt_gene <- data.table("GENE"=c("GENE1","GENE2","GENE3","GENE4","GENE5"), 
                    "START"=c(1000,2100,5000,40000,23000), "END"=c(2000,3000,9000,45000,30000)) ## Gene data
setkey(dt_gene, START, END)

dt_snp[, BP2 := BP]
## do a join using data.table
dt_snp[dt_gene, c("SNP","BP","GENE","START","END"), on=list(BP2 >= START, BP2 <= END), nomatch=0][]
#>      SNP    BP  GENE START   END
#> 1:  SNP1  1100 GENE1  1000  2000
#> 2:  SNP3  2500 GENE2  2100  3000
#> 3:  SNP5  5500 GENE3  5000  9000
#> 4:  SNP8  8800 GENE3  5000  9000
#> 5:  SNP9 23200 GENE5 23000 30000
#> 6: SNP10 27000 GENE5 23000 30000

setkey(dt_snp, BP, BP2)
foverlaps(dt_snp,dt_gene, by.x=c("BP", "BP2"), by.y=c("START","END"), nomatch=NULL, type="any")[, BP2 := NULL][]
#>     GENE START   END   SNP    BP
#> 1: GENE1  1000  2000  SNP1  1100
#> 2: GENE2  2100  3000  SNP3  2500
#> 3: GENE3  5000  9000  SNP5  5500
#> 4: GENE3  5000  9000  SNP8  8800
#> 5: GENE5 23000 30000  SNP9 23200
#> 6: GENE5 23000 30000 SNP10 27000
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Really really helpful. Learned a lot. :) Thanks for your reply~

Comment: why is an extra `[]` is needed at the end of the join? Without that I don't get an error, also on my side the output seems convincing. I see `[]`with foverlaps as well as `list` join.

Comment: You don't need the `[]` at the end - it is just there to display the result in the output. If you assign that to a variable you should omit it.